# plupload with silverlight not working - ok with html5 and flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, silverlight, coffeescript, plupload

Given *runtime silverlight*
when *I click upload button*
then *nothing happens*

Works fine with html5 and flash. I'm testing thoroughly now, as IE bugged with plupload flash (container was not set, which freaked IE out.) To ensure there are no more bugs, I tried testing silverlight as only runtime, sadly resulting in this silent error. IT doesn't work in neither FF, chrome on mac, or IE9 at windows.

I'm using Backbone and coffeescript (Rails 3 app)
This is how I construct the plupload within `class window.Uploader extends Backbone.View`
. Remember, it works with flash and html5 as runtime:

```
initialize: (options) -> 
  @uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'silverlight,flash',  #'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles',
    container: 'upload_container'
    max_file_size : '5mb',
    url : "/admin/upload",
    flash_swf_url : '/publiclib/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '/publiclib/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    filters : [ {title: "#{filter_title} ", extensions : "#{filter_extentions}"}]
    multi_selection: that.multiple,
    multipart: true,
    multipart_params: {
      "authenticity_token" : FORM_AUTH_TOKEN
    },
    file_data_name: 'photo'
  })

  ###### THIS PRINTS SILVERLIGHT as runtime, in all browser I've tested for this Q
  ###### So it is used/detected, but not working
  @uploader.bind 'Init', (up, params) ->
    $('#filelist').html("<div>Current runtime: #{params.runtime} </div>")

  @uploader.init()
  @setupBindings()

setupBindings: ->
  #instantiates the uploader
  that = @

  # shows the progress bar and kicks off uploading
  @uploader.bind 'FilesAdded', (up, files) ->
    _.each files, (file) ->

      $('#filelist').append('<div id="' + file.id + '"><small>' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') </small><b></b>' + '<div class=" percent label notice" style="width:10%;"><span>Laster opp</span></div></div>')

    that.uploader.start()

  #binds progress to progress bar
  @uploader.bind 'UploadProgress', (uploader, file) ->
    # .. some upload code, not relevant to Q
```

this is my _form.html.erb (Forgive me for not loving haml)

```
<div id="upload_container" class="clearfix">
  <div class='input'>
    <div class='clearfix'>
      <%=activity_image @activity%>
    </div>
    <%=link_to "Choose Picture", '#', :id => "pickfiles", :class => "btn small"%>
    <div class='clearfix' id='filelist'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

generated html as requested in comment... :

```
<fieldset>
  <input id="activity_photo_id" name="activity[photo_id]" size="30" style="display:none;" type="text" />

 <legend>choose picture for upload</legend>
 <div id="upload_container" class="clearfix">

   <div class='input'>
     <div class='clearfix'>
       <img src='/assets/default_photo.png' id='image_preview'>
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="btn small" id="pickfiles">Choose Picture</a> 
     <div class='clearfix' id='filelist'></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I click "Choose Picture", nothing happens.

plupload 1.5.1.1

Comment: maybe you could include the generated HTML?

Comment: included. You have a working impl of silverlight plupload? I suspect silverlight doesn't bind to the upload_container or the button, as nothing happens when clicking it. How can I find the area where silverlight listens?

Comment: Is your control in an iframe by any chance? IE7/6 both have issues for me inside of iframes with either flash or silverlight plugins. Works fine once I pulled them out of the iframe and used inline.

Comment: not in iframe. I didn't solve this, I removed silverlight. html5 and flash is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your styling Plupload structure may get lost in your container (#upload_container). Try to wrap browse_button element into it's own container, having a strict position on the screen.

Might be some conflict between Plupload and Backbone/CoffeeScript, cause as standalone thing it works here, tested just now. Can you show your usage case online somewhere?

Comment: I just discoverd the error persists in IE8. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: my `@uploader.bind 'Init'` isn't triggered in IE8 on loading the page. In IE8, I don't see the "Current runtime is.."

Comment: I can help you further, but I really need to see your case. Cause again, as standalone case it works in any IE here. By the way does the example from Plupload's site (http://plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php) work for you in IE8?